# Categorize column according to lists and aggregate with result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, pandas-groupby

Let's say I have a dataframe as follows:

```py
d = {'name': ['spain', 'greece','belgium','germany','italy'], 'davalue': [3, 4, 6, 9, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

```
index name  davalue
0    spain      3
1    greece     4
2    belgium    6
3    germany    9
4    italy      3
```

I would like to aggregate and sum based on a list of strings in the name column.  So for example, I may have: `southern=['spain', 'greece', 'italy']` and `northern=['belgium','germany']`.

My goal is to aggregate by using `sum`, and obtain:

```
index name  davalue
0   southern    10
1   northen     15
```

where `10=3+4+3` and `15=6+9`

I imagined something like:

```py
df.groupby(by=[['spain','greece','italy'],['belgium','germany']])
```

could exist. The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) say

> A label or list of labels may be passed to  group by the columns in self

but I'm not sure I understand what that means in terms of syntax.

Comment: A list of labels would be manually defining you groups by passing a list equal to the number of rows in your dataframe like this. `df.groupby(['southern', 'southern', 'northern', 'northern', 'southern'])['davalue'].sum()`

Comment: @ScottBoston, thank you for the clarification.  Unfortunately there are many more rows than in the real dataset.  But I guess I could build that list with some kind of `df['name'].map()` as suggested by @Quang Hoang

Comment: Exactly!  QuangHoang solution is best.  I was just pointing out to you that is what a list of labels manually would look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would build a dictionary and map:

```
d = {v:'southern' for v in southern}
d.update({v:'northern' for v in northern})

df['davalue'].groupby(df['name'].map(d)).sum()
```

Output:

```
name
northern    15
southern    10
Name: davalue, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

One way could be using [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) and using the result as a grouper:

```
import numpy as np

southern=['spain', 'greece', 'italy']
northern=['belgium','germany']

g = np.select([df.name.isin(southern),
               df.name.isin(northern)],
              ['southern', 'northern'],
              'others')

df.groupby(g).sum()

          davalue
northern       15
southern       10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df["regional_group"]=df.apply(lambda x: "north" if x["home_team_name"] in ['belgium','germany'] else "south",axis=1)
```

You create a new column by which you later groubpy.

```
df.groupby("regional_group")["davavalue"].sum()
```